# What is the preferred way to enqueue just a function in scriptaculous?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous, effects

I have an application, that uses scriptaculous' effects queue to render the view of a game. 
Ajax-requests read events from a server, from these events, effects are generated and enqueued.

Some events have nothing to animate, only code to execute. It is possible, by creating a Dummy-effect, and use the afterFinish option.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can write your own effect class and take advantage of all kinds of Scriptaculous/Prototype goodness.

Here is [an example](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/jameslab/wipe/) I wrote.

Comment: The effect i wrote basically boils down to a DummyEffect, because all i need in this case is the afterFinish-callback.

But I take from your answer that there is now better way that to write own effects, even if they don't do much.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an undocumented Effect-class which is basically my dummy class: Effect.Event(options), which is used internally by scriptaculous. For my purpose (just enqueueing a function) it does the Job.